# Nomi alternativi per città italiane

Tags: vocabulary, name, proper-nouns

Leggo abbastanza spesso sui giornali nomi alternativi di alcune città italiane, sempre con la forma "la città [parola, spesso un'aggettivo]", per esempio 'la città eterna' (Roma), 'la città superba' (Genova), 'la città partenopea' (Napoli), 'la città lagunare' (Venezia), 'la città scaligera' ecc. Esiste una lista di queste forme alternative? Quali sono gli esempi più conosciuti?

Comment: Si tratta in questo caso di "appellativi" -  ho trovato questo articolo
https://www.italianochefatica.it/it/citta-italiane-e-loro-appellativi/

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE!

Answer (score 2):

Gli esempi più conosciuti sono (da [Città italiane e i loro appellativi](https://www.italianochefatica.it/it/citta-italiane-e-loro-appellativi/)):

> **Roma – città eterna, caput mundi**
>
> Roma è una delle città più antiche del mondo e da qui deriva il suo
>   appellativo “città eterna. La chiamano anche “caput mundi”, ovvero
>   “centro/capitale del mondo” perché nell’epoca romana era il punto più
>   importante del mondo conosciuto. Esiste anche il detto “Tutte le
>   strade portano a Roma” perché le arterie principali dell’Impero Romano
>   effettivamente arrivavano a Roma stessa.
>
> **Genova – La Superba**
>
> Per 800 anni, Genova è stata la più grande città marittima d’Europa,
>   una repubblica indipendente, prospera, fiera. La sua potenza era tale
>   che la città veniva e viene anche oggi chiamata “la Superba”.
>
> **Venezia – La Serenissima, La Dominante, La Regina dell’Adriatico**
>
> La città di Venezia è stata per più di un millennio capitale della
>   Repubblica di Venezia, una delle Repubbliche più  ricche e potenti
>   sulla costa Adriatica. E il fatto si rispecchia perfettamente negli
>   appellativi a lei attribuiti: La Serenissima, La Dominante, La Regina
>   dell’Adriatico.
>
> **Bologna – Felsina, La Dotta, La Grassa, La Rossa**
>
> Gli Etruschi, che popolavano l’Italia prima di Romani, chiamavano
>   Bologna – Velzna. In latino questo nome suonava come Felsina. Anche
>   oggi Bologna viene spesso chiamata Felsina, e tutto ciò che riguarda
>   la città viene definito bolognese o felsineo.
>
> Nella città è stata fondata l’Università più antica d’Europa, e da qui
>   il suo altro appellativo “La Dotta”; la cucina bolognese è una delle
>   cucine più famose e amate non solo in Italia ma anche in tutto il
>   mondo, anche se non è ideale se tenete al vostro peso forma, e da qui
>   proviene un altro nome della città – “La Grassa”.
>
> Bologna è chiamata anche “La Rossa” grazie al colore rosso (e relative
>   sfumature) dei palazzi ed edifici della città.
>
> **Catania – Milano del Sud**
>
> Lo sviluppo economico degli anni 60 del 20 sec. ha raggiunto un
>   livello talmente alto che Catania veniva definita la “Milano del Sud”.
>
> **Milano – città meneghina, città Ambrosiana**
>
> Milano chiamano “città Ambrosiana” perché il santo patrono della città
>   e Sant’Ambrogio. E il soprannome “città meneghina” si deve a
>   Meneghino, la maschera della Commedia dell’Arte, legata alla città.
>
> **Napoli – città delle 500 cupole**
>
> Napoli è la città più ricca al mondo di chiese, conventi ed edifici di
>   costruiti nel corso di 17 secoli. E grazie a questa particolarità  nel
>   XVIII secolo al capoluogo campano venne attribuito  l’appellativo di
>   “città dalle 500 cupole”.
>
> **Torino – città magica** Dicono che Torino è uno dei vertici del
>   triangolo della magia bianca assieme alle città di Praga e Lione e da
>   qui deriva l’appellativo di città magica.
>
> **Ferrara – città delle biciclette, città Estense, prima città moderna
>   d’Europa**
>
> Il mezzo di trasporto più popolare nella città è la bicicletta e per
>   questo la chiamano spesso “città delle biciclette”. Grazie ai conti
>   d’Este che governavano Ferrara, la chiamano anche “città Estense”.
>
> Nel Medioevo il centro di Ferrara è stato ricostruito e la città ha
>   raddoppiato l’area urbana e ha preso un aspetto imponente e solenne,
>   con vie larghe e diritte ed edifici simmetrici intervallati da spazi
>   verdi. Grazie a questa imponente impresa urbanistica a Ferrara è stato
>   attribuito l’appellativo di “prima città moderna d’Europa”

La lista non è esaustiva ma copre le principali città.
EDIT: in aggiunta alla lista o ad integrazione delle già presenti:

**Milano**: capitale morale d'Italia, capitale della moda 
**Torino**: città regale, città austera
**Brescia**: Leonessa d'Italia 
**Genova**: porto d'Italia, la Dominante 
**Verona**: città degli innamorati 
**Trieste**: mitteleuropea, città dei caffè 
**Bologna**: turrita (grazie a @Charo)
**Firenze**: culla del Rinascimento 
**Roma**: l'Urbe, la Capitale 
**Napoli**: città del sole 
**Bari**: città del Levante 
**Lecce**: Firenze del Sud, Firenze del Barocco
 
**Messina**: Porta della Sicilia 
**Palermo**: Ziz (Fiore, periodo fenicio), la Splendida (Al Aziz, periodo arabo), Felicissima (XIX sec belle epoque), “rossa, ràisa e palmosa” (da *Il sorriso dell'ignoto marinaio* di Vincenzo Consolo) 
**Siracusa**: “bianca, euriala e petrosa” (da *Il sorriso dell'ignoto marinaio* di Vincenzo Consolo)
**Cagliari**: Casteddu

Comment: E anche **Bologna - la turrita**, no?

Comment: Grazie della risposta. Quello che mi interessa di più sono le forme 'la città [qualcosa]', perché spesso le trovo poco trasparenti e anche perché la loro origine è spesso molto interessante. Per esempio, non conoscevo l'aggettivo 'meneghino', e quindi non avrei mai capito cosa volesse dire 'la città meneghina' senza cercare in internet, e poi il fatto che 'meneghino' derivi dal nome 'Domenico', è per se interessante.

Comment: Anche Pavia è detta "la città delle 100 torri"

Comment: Taranto - La città dei due mari (per la presenza del mar Piccolo, mare interno, ed il mar Grande, esterno alla città)

Answer (score 0):

Pisa come Repubblica era detta la Gloriosa

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE!