# Perché Palermo è qualificata come "ràisa"?

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *Il sorriso dell'ignoto marinaio*, di Vincenzo Consolo, ho letto:

> Ma dove si dirigeva quella ladra speronara, alla volta di Siracusa bianca, euriala e petrosa, o di Palermo rossa, **ràisa** e palmosa?

Sapreste spiegarmi perché Palermo viene qualificata come "ràisa" in questa frase?

Nei dizionari che ho consultato appare il termine "ràis", ma non capisco cosa hanno a che vedere le diverse accezioni di questo vocabolo con Palermo. Per esempio, nel [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/rais) si spiega che, in siciliano, *ràisi* significa "capobarca" e anche che "ràis" vuol dire

> Nelle tonnare di Sicilia, chi dirige l’organizzazione tecnica e comanda gli uomini addetti alle operazioni di pesca

Le altre accezioni che ho trovato definiscono "ràis" come un capo o comandante dei paesi arabi oppure come un capitano di bastimento durante il periodo dell’egemonia ottomana nel Mediterraneo.

Comment: Non può essere che, tra gli attribuiti che dà alla città di Palermo, ci sia appunto quello di “rais femmina”, come se la chiamasse “regina” o “signora” (varie città hanno titoli simili)?

Comment: @DaG: Cioè, si userebbe "ràis" come sinonimo di "capo"? Può darsi...

Comment: È quello che mi verrebbe in mente considerando anche il passato islamico della città di Palermo, ma vediamo se c'è qualcuno che ne sa di più. (Inciso che forse non c'entra niente: l'aeroporto di Palermo si trova in località Punta Raisi, ma non sono riuscito a trovare l'etimo di questo toponimo.)

Comment: *“Punta Raisi (che ha dato il nome all'omonimo aeroporto), viene dall'arabo rais (capo).*” Capo nel senso di estremità, spazio finale, per cui il termine potrebbe far riferimento alla zona di Palermo e in senso più lato, alla città. http://www.virtualsicily.it/Storia-cinisi-PA-344

Comment: Sarei anche curioso del significato di "euriala". Deriva da una delle gorgoni?

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: Ha a che vedere col [Castello Eurialo](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castello_Eurialo).

Comment: @Charo quindi è plausibile che "ràisa" derivi dalla località di Punta Raisi; noto che i tre aggettivi che descrivono le città seguono lo stesso ordine:
bianca, euriala e petrosa;rossa, ràisa e palmosa ovvero
[qualifica di colore];[qualifica di località];[qualifica di aspetto naturale]

Comment: Ma Punta Raisi è relativamente lontana da Palermo (e poco nota se non fosse per l'aeroporto). Sarebbe come chiamare Roma “fiumicina”...

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: Inoltre, questa frase descrive un pensiero di Enrico Pirajno, barone di Mandralisca, in personaggio storico dell'Ottocento.

Comment: Mi limito a notare che gli aggettivi utilizzati sono a coppie bianca/rossa; euriala/raisa; petrosa/palmosa e nello stesso ordine.

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: Hai ragione: questo è interessante, ma non credo che sia un riferimento alla località "Punta Raisi".

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: Penso che gli aggettivi "euriala" e "ràisa" possano essere piuttosto un riferimento al passato storico di queste due città. "Ràisa" potrebbe far riferimento a Palermo come capoluogo dell'Emirato di Sicilia.

Comment: Forse è anche un po' come dire che Siracusa è greca e Palermo è araba (nel senso di un periodo storico di splendore nel passato di queste città).

Comment: Tuttavia, trovo che la frase sia proprio bellissima e, se fosse più conosciuta, si potrebbe aggiungere alla risposta a [questa domanda](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/9027/nomi-alternativi-per-citt%c3%a0-italiane).

Comment: @Charo Ho aggiunto le ulteriori definizioni di Siracusa e Palermo alla risposta che hai segnalato.

Answer (score 5):

Secondo l'articolo *[La lingua di Vincenzo Consolo](http://www.progettoblio.com/downloads/SR5.pdf)* di Gualberto Alvino, apparso nella rivista del [Progetto Oblio](http://www.progettoblio.com/), il vocabolo "ràisa" nel brano citato proviene dal siciliano *rràisi* e significa

> capo, chi comanda, dirige o guida

e quindi farebbe riferimento a Palermo come capoluogo della Sicilia.

Come giustamente segnalato da @RiccardoDeContardi, gli aggettivi usati dall'autore per descrivere le due città siciliane sembrano potersi organizzare semanticamente a coppie: bianca/rossa, euriala/ràisa e petrosa/palmosa. Il termine "euriala" ha a che vedere col [Castello Eurialo](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castello_Eurialo) e quindi farebbe riferimento al passato greco di Siracusa, un periodo storico di splendore di questa città. Quindi, si potrebbe ipotizzare che, in modo analogo, "ràis" (o "ràisa" in questo caso), vocabolo di origine araba che secondo il [dizionario Hoepli](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/R/rais.php) significa

> Nel mondo arabo, comandante, capo, guida

faccia riferimento a Palermo come 
capoluogo dell'Emirato di Sicilia nei tempi del dominio islamico sull'isola, anche un'epoca di splendore per questa città.